# How To Cube A Number In Factor?

Tags: factor-lang

I'm playing with Factor trying to get a little understanding of concatenative programming.  Writing a word to square a number is trivial:

```
: square ( n -- n ) dup * ;
```

But for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to cube a number:

```
: cube ( n -- n ) * * ;  ! Form a
```

Doesn't work because the inferred stack effect is `( x x x -- x )` Similarly

```
: cube ( n -- n ) dup * * ; ! Form b
```

also fails.

If I were to hard code a cube I would do something like this:

```
3 3 * 3 *
```

Which is why my naive guess would be form b.

As I say I'm just playing with Factor and would love to know what I'm missing here--but it's mostly for my curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a builtin word for that:

```
IN: scratchpad 3 3 ^ .
27
```

Or if you want to write the word yourself:

```
: pow ( x n -- y ) 1 - over '[ _ * ] times ;
IN: scratchpad 5 3 pow .
125
```

You could also formulate `cube` using `square`:

```
: cube ( n -- n' ) dup square * ;
IN: scratchpad 6 cube .
216
```

Comment: You do have to add the math.functions vocabulary in order for "^" to work. Minor thing but if anyone else runs across this, just wanted to insure it's apparent.

Comment: Also is there a way to generalize the `3 ^` portion of this word?  I mean something like `: cube ( n -- n ) 3 [ ^ ] ;` (that doesn't work :) )

Comment: Um I guess you could write it as `: cube ( n -- n' ) 3 ^ ;`

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else runs across this and wants to know how to do this:

```
: cube ( n -- n ) dup dup * * ;
```

The `dup dup` will add the value to the top of the stack twice and then the `* *` will multiply twice.  I'd bet there's a less hacky way to do this but, as I say, in case anyone else is curious.

Comment: I think this was what you actually wanted ;), your hard coded version should have been `3 3 3 * *`

Answer (score 3):

This might be interesting to you:

```
: double ( n -- n ) dup + ;   ! add 2 times
: square ( n -- n ) dup * ;   ! multiply 2 times
```

So what about 3 times?

```
: triple ( n -- n ) dup dup + + ;   ! add 3 times
: cube   ( n -- n ) dup dup * * ;   ! multiply 3 times
```

*(I wonder if there is a way to generalize the pattern `[..a a a b b b..]`)*

What about the next [higher order operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation): Tetration:

```
: tetrate2 ( n -- n ) dup ^ ;         ! raise to power twice
: tetrate3 ( n -- n ) dup dup ^ ^ ;   ! raise to power thrice
```

---

You could probably also generalize *the other way*, implementing hyper-operations like Knuth's up arrow.
It's not immediately apparent to me how one would go about doing that,
but Björn's answer seems to hint at it.
The actual source has a lot of abstraction layers optimizing for the different datatypes.
Clicking thru until it reaches `(^fixnum)` gives something similar

Comment: One way to generalize the `dup dup ... op op ...` is what Björn Lindqvist did with the `times` word. Another would be with arrays. `: power ( b e -- n ) swap <array> product ; 5 2 power ! -> 25` (replace `product` with `sum`, or use `reduce` or `each`).

Comment: Be aware that `3 3 ^ 3 ^` is different from `3 3 3 ^ ^`. What you want there is `[ dup ^ ] keep ^`. A generalization: `: tetrate ( x y -- n ) 1 - over <array> [ ^ ] each ;`